# how to assign height and width of widget child(container) from another custom widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout

I want to change my width and height of container widget which is inside custom widget forProducts and I want to pass that width and height from another custom ProductContainer widget but when I pass it in ProductContainer it gives undefined name height and width.

here is my code for this
your help is appreciated,
thank you,

```html
import 'package:myEcomm/screens/info_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List products;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  const ProductContainer({
    Key key,
    this.products,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProductContainerState createState() => _ProductContainerState();
}

class _ProductContainerState extends State<ProductContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: widget.products.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return forProducts(
                    image: widget.products[index]['imageLink'],
                    tag: widget.products[index]['tag'],
                    name: widget.products[index]['name'],
                    category: widget.products[index]["category"],
                    price: widget.products[index]["price"],
                    context: context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget forProducts(
    {String image = "images/",
    @required String tag,
    @required String name,
    @required String category,
    @required String price,
    @required BuildContext context}) {
  return Column(children: [
    Material(
        child: Hero(
            tag: tag,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => InfoPage(
                              image: image,
                              tag: tag,
                              name: name,
                              category: category,
                              price: price,
                            )));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                height:
                    height, // this is the height which I want to assign from productcontainer(height: anyValue) widget
                width:
                    width, // this is the width which I want to assign from productcontainer(width: anyValue) widget
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage(image)),
                ),
              ),
            ))),
    Text(name),
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Passing data around between multiple widgets is really messy. I'd suggest learning state management and start with provider: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Comment: @pskink I tried using that but when I pass  it throws  undefined name `widget` can you tell me in detail how can I use `widget.height` in value of containers height

Comment: I have created a products of type List<map<String,String>> which I am passing in my ProductContainer as `ProductContainer(products: products)` and in that var products has many key value pairs such as `imageLink` `name` etc... but I dont want to define height in there too as it will be used for all as the same value then why to define that in that var. I just want to pass that height to ProductContainer once and use it in forProducts container height.

Comment: @pskink yes you got it right now how can I do that now passing container height of forProducts in ProductContainer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me

```html
import 'package:myEcomm/screens/info_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProductContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  final List products;
  final double height;
  final double width;
  const ProductContainer({
    Key key,
    this.products,
    this.height,
    this.width,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProductContainerState createState() => _ProductContainerState();
}

class _ProductContainerState extends State<ProductContainer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(
            height: 150,
            child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: widget.products.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return forProducts(
                height: widget.height,
                width: widget.width,
                    image: widget.products[index]['imageLink'],
                    tag: widget.products[index]['tag'],
                    name: widget.products[index]['name'],
                    category: widget.products[index]["category"],
                    price: widget.products[index]["price"],
                    context: context);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget forProducts(
    {String image = "images/",
    @required String tag,
    @required String name,
    @required String category,
    @required String price,
    @required double height,
    @required double width,
    @required BuildContext context}) {
  return Column(children: [
    Material(
        child: Hero(
            tag: tag,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => InfoPage(
                              image: image,
                              tag: tag,
                              name: name,
                              category: category,
                              price: price,
                            )));
              },
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                height: height,
                width: width,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      fit: BoxFit.cover, image: AssetImage(image)),
                ),
              ),
            ))),
    Text(name),
  ]);
}
```